# Why builder() method of Lombok is not coming in the suggestion for me in Spring tool Suite in Spring Boot Project?

Tags: java, lombok

I am not getting the Suggestion from IDE for Building and Object using the Lombok Builder Feature Please refer the Line Number 34 in the attached Image.

Below is Reference Image please look at Line Number 34 Where it is not showing builder() method for my Entity Class

[image: Below is Reference Image please look at Line Number 34 Where it is not showing builder() method for my Entity Class]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is *neither* in your code *nor* in your Maven configuration, but it is your IDE (Spring Tool Suite in your case) which is not "Lombok-aware".

Lombok works in the way that it generates the code for you in the compile-time, so the code does not exist in your source code files. Hence the IDE cannot suggest you the generated methods, unless it becomes "Lombok-aware" and pre-generates the Lombok-generated code for the suggestion tips.

For this you need to install a *Lombok plugin*. Each IDE has its own Lombok plugin, some IDE distributions come with the Lombok plugin bundled. Search for STS if the plugin is pre-installed and if not, how to install it.